# Horrible sql server performance when capturing result in variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

When I run this query...

```
select 
    count(*)
from 
    MembershipStatusHistory msh
join 
    gym.Account a on msh.AccountID = a.AccountID
join 
    gym.MembershipType mt on a.MembershipTypeID = mt.MembershipTypeID
join 
    MemberTypeGroups mtg on mt.MemberTypeGroupID = mtg.MemberTypeGroupID
where 
    mtg.MemberTypeGroupID IN (1,2)
    and msh.NewMembershipStatus = 'Cancelled'
    and year(msh.ChangeDate) = year(getdate())
    and month(msh.ChangeDate) = month(getdate())
    and day(msh.ChangeDate) = day(getdate())
```

...it returns almost instantly. Great. Now, when I run the same exact query like this:

```
declare @CancellationsToday int

SET @CancellationsToday = (
    select  
        count(*)
    from MembershipStatusHistory msh
    join gym.Account a
    on msh.AccountID = a.AccountID
    join gym.MembershipType mt
    on a.MembershipTypeID = mt.MembershipTypeID
    join MemberTypeGroups mtg
    on mt.MemberTypeGroupID = mtg.MemberTypeGroupID
    where mtg.MemberTypeGroupID IN (1,2)
    and msh.NewMembershipStatus = 'Cancelled'
    and year(msh.ChangeDate) = year(getdate())
    and month(msh.ChangeDate) = month(getdate())
    and day(msh.ChangeDate) = day(getdate())
)
```

...it takes 1.5 MINUTES to return. Consistently, every time.

What the **** is going on? I have to use a variable because I need to sum the result later on in my stored proc. I am storing the results of other queries in the same proc and they are fast. I am stumped.

Here is the execution plan from the SLOW query:
[image]

And here is the execution plan from the FAST query:
[image]

I'll be honest, I don't know what these execution plans mean or what I need to correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very strange but try something like this....

```
declare @CancellationsToday int;

select @CancellationsToday = count(*)
from MembershipStatusHistory msh
join gym.Account a
on msh.AccountID = a.AccountID
join gym.MembershipType mt
on a.MembershipTypeID = mt.MembershipTypeID
join MemberTypeGroups mtg
on mt.MemberTypeGroupID = mtg.MemberTypeGroupID
where mtg.MemberTypeGroupID IN (1,2)
and msh.NewMembershipStatus = 'Cancelled'
and year(msh.ChangeDate) = year(getdate())
and month(msh.ChangeDate) = month(getdate())
and day(msh.ChangeDate) = day(getdate())
```

Comment: @@ROWCOUNT always returns "1" instead of the COUNT number. At first I was optimistic, because it did run very fast. Any ideas? Do I have to do SELECT * instead of SELECT count(*) ?

Comment: Hold on, using SELECT * won't work, because some of my counts return hundreds of thousands of records, and those will all be returned to my app, which seems really inefficient when all I need is the count. There must be a better way.

Comment: M.Ali, you nailed it. This seems like a bug in mssql, why it would treat those 2 so differently. Anyway, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Mmmm strange, try this:

```
SELECT @CancellationsToday = COUNT(*) FROM ......
```

Another thing worth to mention is don't use functions in the `WHERE` clause.

I think you have only the date in `msh.ChangeDate`, make a variable with today's date like this:

```
DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

and use that in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: msh.ChangeDate is database data - it is never equal to getdate(). I tried SELECT @, but it's no faster.

Comment: I think he means declare a variable called today, and set it equal to DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())), and then compare a similar expression in the WHERE clause:  WHERE DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, msh.ChangeDate)) = today  ... that alone should be more efficient than six function calls and comparisons on Year/Month/Day

Comment: Ok, sorry I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the execution plans for both queries in SQL Server Management Studio to understand what's going on and why.  There may be an index you can add that will fix things, or the plan itself may tell you what's going side-ways and how to fix it.  Without that info, it's hard to know what to say here.

As I commented above, adjusting your where clause to get rid of the six function calls and just compare the "date" portion of the database column with a constant variable should help some.

Another minor suggestion would be to be explicit about INNER JOIN if that's what you want... always specify exactly the type of join you want (INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN, CROSS JOIN, etc.) instead of just 'join'.  It makes things more clear.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this and report back Monday morning.